# Edit Windows Context Menu entries after right-click drag and drop operation

Tags: windows-7, windows, drag-and-drop, right-click

In the Windows registry, where can I find the Context Menu items for Explorer right mouse button drag & drop?

In Windows Explorer when you right-click and hold on a folder then move the cursor to desktop you get a "Move here", "Copy here", etc menu. I would like to add items or see what items are there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for DragDropHandlers:

```
HKCR\*\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKCR\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKCR\Drive\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKCR\Folder\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers\

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shellex\DragDropHandlers\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers\
```

Comment: These are only the registered extensions for drag-drop.